# cellforrowatindexpath not called after reloaddata swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, xcode-6.2

If I'm managing getting the data inside TableViewController, everything works perfectly, but as I want to move logic outside VC, when I'm triggering reloadData() from outside VC it is not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath and I data is not visible in the table. But numberOfSectionsInTableView or numberOfRowsInSection are being called, what is interesting. I tried many things: triggering reloadData on the main thread, property observers, Notification Center, but nothing seems to work, cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called.

Comment: Is `numberOfRowsInSection` returning a number larger than zero?

Comment: I am following MVC architecture, so we have a one UIView class with UITbaleviewDataSource and Delegate as well. Datasource and delegate has been mapped via NIB and set in code as well.

Comment: yes, numberOfRowsInSection returning larger than zero.  @ABakerSmith

Answer (score 0):

so when you initialize the TableView, you should add

tableView.datasource = self;